# How to write nested if in makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

How do I use multiple nested if-then blocks in a Makefile?

E.g.

```
$(NAMING_SCHEME).$(COMPRESS_TYPE):
ifeq ($(COMPRESS_TYPE),lz4)
    if [ ${LOG_LEVEL} -gt 0 ] ; then \
        @echo hi \
        if [ ${LOG_LEVEL} -gt 1 ] ; then \
            @echo hi again \ 
            if [ ${LOG_LEVEL} -gt 2 ] ; then \
                @echo hi for the last time!!! \ 
            fi; \
        fi; \
    fi; 
endif
```

This results in

```
bin/sh: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token 'then'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: 'ifeq (1, 1)'
make: *** [Makefile:22: program_name.1.2.3.lz4] Error 1
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Have you gotten this shell command to work on the command line?

Comment: You've made some syntax errors. If you _try something simpler first,_ like a single conditional, and get it working perfectly, you'll see what they are.

Comment: Many thanks, this got me to where I needed to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per beta and vonbrand's suggestions I was able to make it work, thanks a million!

```
ifeq ($(COMPRESS_TYPE),lz4) 
    if [ ${LOG_LEVEL} -gt 0 ] ; then \
        echo 111 ${LOG_LEVEL} ;\
        if [ ${LOG_LEVEL} -gt 1 ] ; then \
            echo 222 ${LOG_LEVEL} ;\
            if [ ${LOG_LEVEL} -gt 2 ] ; then \
                echo 333 ${LOG_LEVEL} ;\
            fi \
        fi \
    fi
endif
```

This outputs (in Windows cmd):

```
if [ 2 -gt 0 ] ; then \
        echo 111 2 ;\
        if [ 2 -gt 1 ] ; then \
                echo 222 2 ;\
                if [ 2 -gt 2 ] ; then \
                        echo 333 2 ;\
                fi \
        fi \
fi
111 2
222 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`make` ships off each line to the shell on it's own, thus mutilating your command. To continue a line, end it with a backslash (`\`).